# 3D tracked camera is clipping object out, how to fix it?

Tags: camera, tracking, clipping

Thank you for reading this post.

This is what happened:

I first solved the camera tracking in one .blend file and then exported the camera as an Alembic(.abc)
Then I opened a new .blend and import the camera Alembic(.abc).
The clipping issue happened as shown in the below video.

Left side is the normal 3D layout, right side is the camera viewport, where clipping happened.
[image]

Shouldn't the camera tracking only control the motion of the camera? Why my object is clipping out? How to fix it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by increasing the "Clip End" property in the camera's object data properties.

[image: Camera's clip end]